# Storing app constants in database

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am creating little blog app. Here is a snippet from my views:
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from blog.post.models import Post, Comment
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import Http404

PAGE_SIZE = 5
ABSTRACT_CONTENT_SIZE = 300

def main(request, page = 0):
    post_objects = Post.objects.filter(visible = True)[page : page + PAGE_SIZE]
    posts = []
    for p in post_objects:
        if len(p.content) > ABSTRACT_CONTENT_SIZE:
            abstract = p.content[:ABSTRACT_CONTENT_SIZE] + '...'
        else:
            abstract = p.content
        posts.append({
        'subject': p.subject,
        'content': abstract,
        'author': p.author,
        'date': p.date,
        'noc': p.number_of_comments,
        'number': p.pk
        })
    return render_to_response('main.html',{'posts': posts})
```

I would like to put those 2 constants into database (so I could later manage them from admin). The question is, how should I load them in views, or maybe there is another way to perform this task? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class SiteSettings(models.Model):
      value = models.IntegerField() # Assuming you are only using integer value 
      type  = models.CharField(unique=True) # could also make this the primary key


PAGE_SIZE = SiteSettings.Objects.filter(type="page_size").get()  
# you should be able to do this as well since type is unique
PAGE_SIZE = SiteSettings.Objects.get(type="page_size")
PAGE_SIZE.value
```

Comment: And where to put that 'get()' method? Inside each method or when importing view? Regarding model. I thought creating singleton, but your model is more appealing :)

Comment: get is a built in method of django model class that will return one object/record.

Comment: other way. Where does 6th line of your snippet belong?

Comment: Well you could put it in your veiw.py, so were you have PAGE_SIZE = 5. You could add them to another module and import them as needed. I usually have an extra module called lib where I add code that I might use through a Django project.

Answer (score 1):

Check [all this configuration apps](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/configuration/) to store site-wise info in your databse